# Getting a win32ui.error: CreateFile when trying to save a screenshot with python and winapi

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

The following is my code:

```
import sys
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

def get_windows_bytitle(title_text):
    def _window_callback(hwnd, all_windows):
        all_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))
    windows = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(_window_callback, windows)
    return [hwnd for hwnd, title in windows if title_text in title]

def screenshot(hwnd, filename):
    l,t,r,b = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
    h = b - t
    w = r - l
    hDC = win32gui.GetDC(hwnd)
    myDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hDC)
    newDC = myDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

    myBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    myBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(myDC, w, h)

    newDC.SelectObject(myBitMap)

    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
    sleep(.2) #lame way to allow screen to draw before taking shot
    newDC.BitBlt((0,0),(w, h) , myDC, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    myBitMap.Paint(newDC)
    myBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(newDC, "c:\\bla.bmp")

def main():
    try:
        hwnd = get_windows_bytitle("Chrome")[0]
    except IndexError:
        print("Chrome window not found")
        sys.exit(1)

    screenshot(hwnd, str(datetime.now().microsecond) + ".bmp")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It works great on one PC, but running now on my laptop raises the following error for some reason:

```
win32ui.error: CreateFile
```

Can't find any info regarding that exception online... For the record (if it makes a difference) I installed the winapi on this laptop using the following package from pypi:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

because installing the regular pywin32 didn't work.
Also, now that I think of it, this machine is Windows 8.1 as opposed to Windows 7 on the machine that runs it fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some permission issue on `C:\` and hence it must be failing. Create temp folder (or whatever name you like) and modify your code as shown below

```
myBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(newDC, "c:\\temp\\bla.bmp")
```

Note: ensure that temp folder exist.

Comment: Nice answer. FYI the default filesystem permissions prohibit the creation of files (but not folders) in the root of C:.